# Identification of a particular animated version of "A Christmas Carol"

Tags: story-identification, animation

There probably have been more TV adaptations of Charles Dickens' "A Christmas Carol" than any other story in history, but I'm trying to identify a particular one that was shown for a few years running on British TV at Christmas during the mid 1970s. It was a cartoon, and I think it was about 40 minutes long. I'm not sure if it was made in Britain or in Europe, though I'm fairly sure it wasn't American. I've no idea who any of the voice actors were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you said you were *fairly* sure it wasn't an American production, it would be somewhat remiss of me not to mention the [1971 animated TV short](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068373/):

Although it was produced by ABC and initially shown on their networks only, it later received a theatrical release and [won an Academy Award](http://www.oscars.org/oscars/ceremonies/1973) in 1973, so it wouldn't surprise me if it had been shown outside the US.

It also starred [Alastair Sim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alastair_Sim) and [Michael Hordern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Hordern), reprising the roles of Scrooge and Marley from the classic [1951 live-action adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044008/), so it would be understandable if you'd mistakenly believed it to be a British production.

Comment: This is the one I was remembering, although I probably saw the Australian one too which is why I thought it was about 40 minutes long. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There was [an animated adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0452599/) made in Australia in 1969, 45 minutes long. It's on Youtube:

I wasn't watching much British television in the 1970s, but the timing works and Australia has a history of exporting television to the UK (and other places; one of the reviews on the IMDB page mentions watching it on CBS in America)